# ActiveMQ Failover Transport -

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am using the active mq failover configuration in my Spring Web based application. There are 4 production active mq boxes and my connection URL for a message producer looks like this

failover:(tcp://hosta:61616,tcp://hostb:61616,tcp://hostc:61616,tcp://hostd:61616)

The failover piece works fine. When a producer tries send message, connection gets established on any of the 4 nodes and if that fails, it goes to a other node.

All is fine here. But if the second host fails, the next one does not get picked up and it sends an exception to the client.

There is only one level of failover that I am able to witness . Do we have to make any additional configuration to make sure all active mq hosts are checked before throwing out an exception to the client.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which AMQ version?
What exception?
If you want to connect to a, then b, then c, then d. You should have `?randomize=false` appended to your connection string.
Still won't explain why you can only connect to two machines though.

Comment: How are the 4 hosts set up? Are they all running in a master-slave setup, are they all standalone, or a network of brokers? Can you also say which version of ActiveMQ, and give a copy of the exception?